# ¿Como convertir numeros separados en un numero final?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una función que convierte letras en numeros:(sin usar el método parseInt() original de JS)

```
console.log(parseInt("one")) // devuelve 1
console.log(parseInt("twenty")) // devuelve 20
console.log(parseInt("two thousand forty-six")) // devuelve 2046
```

Hasta ahora lo que he logrado es que devuelve los numeros separados:

```
console.log(parseInt("one")) // devuelve [1]
console.log(parseInt("twenty")) // devuelve [20]
console.log(parseInt("two thousand forty-six")) // devuelve [2, 1000, 40, 6]
```

¿Como hacer la lógica en un for loop para "sumar" esos números correctamente y den 2046?

He escrito esto:

```js
        var numberContainer = [2, 1000, 40, 6]
        var definitiveNumber = 0;
        
        
        for (let i=0;i<numberContainer.length;i++){
          if (numberContainer[i+1] > numberContainer[i]){
            let operacion = numberContainer[i] * numberContainer[i+1]
            definitiveNumber += operacion
          }
          else if (numberContainer[i+1] < numberContainer[i]){
            let operacion = numberContainer[i] + numberContainer[i+1]
            definitiveNumber += operacion
          }
        }

        return definitiveNumber
```

Lo que pasa es que en vez de `numberContainer[i+1] > numberContainer[i]` en vez de poner "mayor", quiero poner "que sea mayor en decenas(o como se diga, cuando el numero tiene un cero más)", y en el otro if else que sea "menor en decenas(o como se diga, cuando el numero sea inferior teniendo un cero menos, al menos)".

Comment: Creo que una posible implementación seria darle la vuelta al array. Así siempre tendrías el vector como [unidades, decenas, centenas, millares,...]. Creo que se te simplificaría bastante el calculo.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma más sencilla que veo es como te comento en el comentario, darle la vuelta al vector.

```
var numerContainerReverse = numberContainer.reverse()
```

Haciendo esto, sabes en todo momento lo que tienes en cada posición del vector:

[unidades, decenas, centenas, unidades de millar, decenas de millar, centenas de millar,...]

Por lo que tendrías que hacer sumas.
No he sido capaz de hacerlo programando, pero te pongo un ejemplo.

var numerContainerReverse = [6,40,300,1000,3,5]

1. Unidades + decenas + centenas. (6 + 40 + 300 = 346)
2. Unidades de millar (he visto que te viene como 1000) + decenas de millar * 10.000 + centenas de millar * 100.000. (1000 + 3*10.000 + 5*100.000) = 532.000
3. Sumar al número anterior. (531.346)

Si tuvieras solo el primer dígito en cada caso seria algo más sencillo.
Puedes aprovechar el indice `i`, para multiplicarlo por la base 10.

```js
var numberContainerReverse = [6,4,3,1,3,5]
var resultado = 0;

for (let i=0; i<numberContainerReverse.length;i++)
{
    resultado = resultado + (numberContainerReverse[i]*Math.pow(10, i));
}

console.log(resultado)
```